# what is the average distance between any two points on a unit circle? can we derive a general formula for the same for all regular polygons?

Tags: integration, geometry

I have solved a similar problem involving a unit square but I can't seem to figure this one out. Please help!
My first thought was to take the average of the upper and lower value but it didn't work.

I tried co-ordinate geometry but it didn't work as well.
The answer to the first question is $4/\pi \approx 1.27$

Comment: In what sense did it not work? Do you know what the correct answer is? How did you solve the unit square problem? What are the other methods you tried? Please [edit] the question to include these and any other details or context.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: If you have a new question you should ask a new question. Do not edit closed questions to fundamentally change the question.

Answer (score 2):

Select any two points on a unit circle. The shortest distance between them is the length of the chord that passes through those points. The length of that chord will be $2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$ where $\theta$ is the angle that the chord subtends on the centre of the circle.

Now here's a formula

> The mean of a function $f(x)$ over the interval $[a, b]$ is $\frac1{b – a}$ times the integral of the function from $a$ to $b$. For the distance function, we have the angle ranging from $[0, π]$, so the average value is:

$$\textrm{average value}=\frac{1}{\pi-0}\int_0^\pi2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\:\:d\theta$$
$$=\frac{1}{\pi}\left(-4\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\right)_0^\pi$$
$$=\boxed{\frac{4}{\pi}}$$

Comment: There are many pairs of points having some fixed $\theta$ as the angle subtended by chord. So I am little confuse about how you get that formula

Answer (score 1):

Two points separated by an angle $\theta$ have a distance
$$
d(\theta)=2R\, \sin(\theta /2)
$$
then the average distance is obtained by integrating
$$
\overline{d}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int _{0}^{2\pi} \, d\theta \  d(\theta)=\frac{4R}{\pi}
$$